# Axiom of Choice to build a set of real numbers not Lebesgue measurable

Tags: measure-theory, logic, measurable-sets

below is an extract of the book (at the very beginning) of "The Axiom of Choice" by Jech. I am having a hard time at understanding this introductory example, that shows how to construct a set of real numbers not Lebesgue measurable, using the axiom of choice :

[image: Jech Axiom of Choice 1]

[image: Jech Axiom of Choice 2]

The thing I'm particularly confused with is the fact that the equivalence relation is defined for $x, y$ both in $[0,1]$, but yet he seems to assign any real number to the equivalence classes. How can he define something only on $[0,1]$ and assert (but I might be wrong):

$$\mathbb{R} = \{ [y] : y \in [0,1]\} = \left\{ \{y + r : r\in \mathbb{Q}\} : y \in [0,1]\right\}$$

The last part also is not that obvious to me. Isn't it wrong to say:

$$\left\{ \{y + r : r\in \mathbb{Q}, 0\leq r \leq 1 \} : y \in [0,1]\right\} \subset [0,1]$$

Thanks for your help

**EDIT**

Ok I understand some things more:

$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, x - \lfloor x \rfloor \in [0, 1]$$

and then there exists a unique rational $r' \in [0,1]$  and a unique real $y \in [0,1]$ such that $x = y + \underbrace{r' + \lfloor x \rfloor}_{r\in\mathbb{Q}}$.

Then:
$$\begin{align}
\mu(\mathbb{R}) &= \mu(\bigcup\limits_{r\in\mathbb{Q}} M_r) \\
&= \sum_{r\in\mathbb{Q}} \mu(M_r) \quad\text{ (since it's a partition)} \\
&= \sum_{r\in\mathbb{Q}} \mu(M) \\
&= +\infty . \mu(M)
\end{align}$$

So with the convention that $+\infty.0 = 0$, I understand the first contradiction ($\mu(M) = 0$)

but I don't understand the last inequality, I don't think we have, right?:

$$\bigcup\limits_{r\in[0,1]\cap\mathbb{Q}} M_r \subset [0,1]$$

Answer (score 1):

He's not asserting that $\mathbb{R}$ is the union of the $\sim$-classes; as you say, that union would just be $[0,1]$.

Rather, he's saying $$\mathbb{R}=\bigcup_{r\in\mathbb{Q}}M_r,$$ where $$M_r=\{y+r: y\in M\}.$$ Note that $M_r$ is **not** in general a subset of $[0,1]$ - consider e.g. $M_{17}$.

Your second question runs into the same issue.

Comment: thanks, I edited my question as I understood some thing with your help